# Do I stay or do I go? Undervalued and valued at the same time

Tags: professionalism, work-environment, resignation

I started a new job about 8 months ago. I am quite experienced and skilled at what I do. Since I joined I seem to be getting more and more work piled on. My initial role I still do, but I did it very well. So I also took on the email marketing when they were having issues with another employee. So I was doing my original job plus the design, build, implementation and writing of the quite considerable number of email campaigns they run.

Then the dropship manager left and I now do my original role, the email marketing, and now look after all the dropshippers (which was a full time job for another employee that was never replaced). Now a new key account sales manager has been employed, and with the additional emails he wants, and as the "reliable one" in the office, he now uses me as his sales support, because it seems I am the only one he can rely on to get things done.

On top of that, I now support the warehouse manager with several order systems, so every morning I am supporting him, helping to manage all the orders from multiple systems, for a few hours every day.

Yet, the digital marketing manager, that just manages ebay, amazon and one retail site (which I help fix when it goes wrong as he is not a developer), gets paid more than me, so does the sales manager, the key account manager and the general manager. However, apart from doing the job now of what was originally three other people, plus supporting the customer services staff, plus doing my original job and two others, plus running and managing the other three sales channels, which equal the sales income of the digital managers sites, and managing the same level of growth, I am now being asked to do the digital marketing for the channels I manage.

I work so hard, I am the first in every morning, about an hour before anyone else, I work weekends and bank holidays trying to keep up. I cannot cope with any more, and already I can see the massive overload is starting to affect the quality I can do with any of them.

But, it has been hinted at that I am very valuable and I am treated very well. There have been hints at promotions in the future etc. All the more junior staff say how they enjoy working with me, and how much better everything is since I joined. Even the warehouse staff say these things even though there is a rift between the office and the warehouse, I seem to bridge that gap quite easily.

Now I hear on the grapevine that the whole company is moving next year to a place I have no interest in relocating to, and is, instead of a 30 minute commute, over an hours commute. However, having addressed this directly with the owner, it appears that it is just a possibility, not a concrete plan.

Feeling deflated, undervalued and definitely overworked, I have a CV service  writing a CV for me. But I am still not sure if I should start job hunting or let this opportunity play out.

I really like the place, the owner, the people I work with, and in truth, I also get to run around, unquestioned, doing whatever I like. I literally report to no one. Is it too good a role to give up or am I being taken advantage of? I really do not know what to do.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. What is the best way to approach my boss about this situation, and what approach could I take to reduce the overwork without affecting my standing. Or does a leopard never change its spots and should I just start job hunting?

Comment: Try talking to your boss about your increased role, how to manage your work/life balance, possibly how to move some stuff off your plate, and your compensation given the increased responsibilities. Take a look at https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid

Comment: Definitely look into talking to your boss about alleviating your workload. It is obvious you provide a lot of value, but you are not a machine and they need to stop pretending you are since you're definitely going to burn out eventually. Get your CV prepared in case, but def talk to your boss about your concerns.

Comment: You are valued by the company based on what you cost. You are cheap, therefore you are not valued. You work lots of overtime, probably for free, that means you are valued even less. If you think about leaving, tell your boss that you will be working forty hours a week unless he pays for your overtime, and use the spare time to look for a job elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three comments thus far are useful but you want an answer.

You say it's great there, is it a lot better elsewhere; where do the Dropshippers jump ship to? - Grass is always greener on the other side of the fence.

Does your pay increase with each added task, getting rid of paid employees and getting the rest to pick up the slack is common (and cheaper) but sandbagging one person is not; are you the Manager, ask to supervise since 'everyone' thinks you can do everything.

I have found that sometimes the opposite occurs, they hire you but can't afford much because it's slow. Then they hire a half dozen more people. One third of the new hires are useful, one third have never done that kind of work and are looking for a new job, and one third are anti-productive (but they work for the minimum and the Owner accepts no complaints) - all the while you're working like crazy.

Often everyone is everyone's "pal", everyone is great, your the best. Even when you give your resignation "it's all good" - you have to actually (literally) stick your foot out the door for them to believe it, then there's a scene.

I've called places back at Christmas or New Year's to wish everyone well and the Owner seemed to appreciate the calls - once he'd finished running the place into the ground such calls were no longer acceptable.

You shouldn't work too much OT though some is reasonable. You shouldn't have to many Hats to wear and let your working strengths suffer to cover HR's inability to do their own job.

Make certain work equals money, and you have time/energy to enjoy your riches.

Probably stick with it, (all caps) leave your current employer OFF OF your resume and simply generalize what you do (caps off) and how long you worked there - don't risk someone calling your current employer, if they insist to know try elsewhere.

When your certain of a better offer approach the Owner about making some changes. Save up for the company moving and let that be your great reason for leaving.

Don't let a bad week or month sour a few great months.

Cherry pick what you will do, including what you were hired for, and let the other stuff go to the new hires; no one newly hired?, is that why YOU were hired ...

It's got to be fair to everyone, even the customers, who is losing the most ... (shouldn't be the employee who 'pays').

If you have a friend who already left (and isn't going to call the boss) discuss with them if they regret leaving; perhaps they want someone to put in a good word and to return, maybe leaving was for the best.

Eight months is both long to stay (if it's bad) and quick to leave (if it's good) - won't help your resume much if you quit.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I will heed your advice, get my CV primed (great idea to leave off the company contact details and name of current employer - had not thought of that) and stay a while longer, until a move at least is certain. I will also talk about this with my boss and see if I can supervise more officially and get a pay rise. I am also going to stop working at weekends and late evenings. This has made me feel really positive, as what you said makes great sense, and has really helped. Thanks.

Comment: > "... feel really positive ..." - Excellent. I am in a position where I can leave off the current employer and the receiver of the resume knows it's wonderful and they enjoy it, alternately they can chuck it in the trash. I do difficult highly profitable work that others don't like and can't do. Evidence (to me) of that is given the choice of hiring me, someone else, or closing they often close. I can do 1000's of dollars of work a day, no one can mess around without that money being lost. In your position it sounds like you're the glue that holds everything together, they MUST see that.

Comment: It does feel that way in truth, and others have said it without prompting. I have a meeting arranged tomorrow with the general manager. I am asking for an assistant, a pay rise, a change of job title, a bigger budget and have solutions drawn up for a range of problems. Looking forward to it immensely. At the same time I have my CV being written and some holiday request forms for a week off which I may or may not use. Thanks again. Your input has really opened my eyes to what I have not been doing. Sometimes you just cannot see the wood for the trees.

Comment: Leave the "Solutions" in your head and say them after you get some/all of the other requests. If you drop all that in their lap along with the solutions then letting you go and hoisting all that on someone else will cost less. Be careful to not blast the person, to overplay your hand. They may not understand your value and simply wrongly think you are the only problem. Best to explain how much you do and ask for a raise, then suggest that you will take on the role of finding an assistant (unless there's an HR and they are capable of doing that). Check they agree on payday before going too far.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I will do exactly that. Now you say it, it seems obvious. I was just now writing a presentation, have dropped that too following your comment, in favor of a conversation. Makes more sense. Can you come to the meeting with me please Rob, or at least 'mission impossible' style bug in my ear, advising  :-) But seriously, thank you again. Just making some notes to clarify my approach now. Once again, much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Your welcome. Good luck. Owners often pay for a shiny building, a great reception area, sometimes reasonable sized work areas with great equipment - but when it comes to giving money to a person it's like it's a waste and somehow there's a way to shortcut or shortchange that can work in their favor. Part of it is wage vs. what the customer pays; when you're getting less than 1/3 you are subsidizing the wage - when there's no work you still get paid or they risk losing you to greener pastures. The other part is then everyone else wants fairness and their overdue raise. Penny smart / £ stupid.